# Display checkbox list in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to display a checkbox list and save the checked values to the database in MVC 2 but so far i  didn't able to display the checkbox list on the view. below is the code i'm having.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class Address
    {
        public int addressID { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
    }

 public class Client
    {
        public int ClientID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Client> ClientOrdersGrid { get; set; }
        public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; } 
        public List<int> SelectedAddressIDs { get; set; }

    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            JqGridClientRepository rep = new JqGridClientRepository();

            Address ad=new Address() {address="abcd",addressID=1};
            Address ad1=new Address() {address="kandy",addressID=2};
            Address ad2=new Address() {address="colombo",addressID=3};

            List<Address> lstAd=new List<Address>(){
                ad,ad1,ad2

            };

            var model = new Client()
            {
                Addresses = lstAd,
                ClientOrdersGrid=rep.GetClients()//This method gets an IEnumerable list of all clients

            };

            return View(model);
    }
```

**View:**

```
 <% foreach (var item in Model.Addresses) { %>

      // I want to display checkbox list of addresses here   

    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified some fields on your model like

```
public class Address
    {
        public int addressID { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public bool AddreChecked { get; set; }
    }
```

and changed some line of code in view as

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Addresses)
{
    <div>&nbsp;</div> 
    @Html.CheckBox("checkboxGroup", item.AddreChecked); @item.address
}
```

Hope this help!